# Epsilon-Delta proof of $\lim_{x \to 2} 2x^2 + 3x = 14$.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I'm stuck on the epsilon-delta proof of a limit. Namely, Consider the function $f(x) = 2x^2 + 3x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 < x < 4$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 14$.

By the definition of a limit: $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta > 0 \, \forall x(0 < |x-2|<\delta \Longrightarrow |2x^2 + 3x -14|< \epsilon)$$
So, to find $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$: $ \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, |2x^2 + 3x -14| < \epsilon
\\ \Longleftrightarrow |(2x+7)(x-2)|<\epsilon 
\\ \Longleftrightarrow|2x+7|\cdot|x-2|<\epsilon$

Now, since, I'm given that $0 < x < 4$. I could deduce, $|x-2| <2$, and $|2x+7| < 7$. But, I'm unsure how to use these inequalities to get $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0<x<4$ one has that $|2x+7|<15$ and since $|x-2|<\delta$ choosing $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{15}$ you get
$$|2x+7||x-2|<15\cdot \delta=15\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{15}=\varepsilon$$
as you desired to prove.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, I'm confused about $0<x<4$, doesn't this also imply that $|x-2| < 2$, meaning $\delta = 2$?. So, is $\delta = 2$ or $\frac{\epsilon}{15}$?

Comment: For continuity, you need to choose your $\delta$ in accordance with your $\varepsilon$. If you choose $\delta = 2$, then $\vert 2x+7 \vert \vert x-2 \vert < 15\cdot\delta = 30$, which is fine, if $\varepsilon = 30$, but you want this to hold for $\textbf{every}$ $\varepsilon > 0$. And as you see above, this follows if you choose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{15}$.

Comment: @stange Thank you for the explanation. This makes sense to me!